# Flash ads for adwords: Using mouse tracking error

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, google-ads-api

I just created a flash ad using Adobe Flash CS6 with a textarea and a dropdown. I tried to submit it to adwords but it keeps telling me i have mouse tracking in my code. What should I do?

```
import flash.net.navigateToURL;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.net.URLVariables;

bb.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoToWebPage);

function fl_ClickToGoToWebPage(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    var dir_web:String = root.loaderInfo.parameters.clickTAG;
    var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(dir_web);
    var urlVars:URLVariables = new URLVariables();

    urlVars.askText = askTextOnStage.text;
    urlVars.category = cb.selectedItem.data;
    request.data = urlVars;
    request.method="POST";

    navigateToURL(request,"_blank");
}
```

Comment: I removed the Flex tag; as this does not have anything to do w/ the Adobe/Apache UI Framework.

Comment: were you able to find any solution to this???  I also tried so many thing and it says me mouse tracking error. I can find that this is only happening because of textarea.

Comment: @VikashAgrawal The solution is you have to change POST to GET. And i have another problem with having a flash default drop down menu, which is not compatible with google, you have to customize one!

Comment: Thanks @jackhao but this does not work and still it says Mouse Tracking is disallowed. I have a button and textarea.

Comment: @VikashAgrawal Get rid of every POST and GET and see what happened

Comment: :-( Bad luck. I tried this too and same error. The thing is this: with only button and click tag I am able to upload but immediately after adding textarea / input box it doesn't allow me to upload in adwords saying "Mouse Tracking". It will be great if you can help me in this.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably reading your code and finding a string or two in it that it doesn't like.

Try changing

`bb.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoToWebPage);`

to

`bb.addEventListener('CLICK', fl_ClickToGoToWebPage);`

and change

`function fl_ClickToGoToWebPage(event:MouseEvent):void`

to

`function fl_ClickToGoToWebPage(event:*):void`

Good luck!

Answer (score -2):

You need to drop the URLVariables and POST. Your code should be simplified to this:

```
bb.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoToWebPage);

function fl_ClickToGoToWebPage(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    var dir_web:String = root.loaderInfo.parameters.clickTAG;
    var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(dir_web);

    navigateToURL(request,"_blank");
}
```

More information [here](https://support.google.com/dfp_sb/answer/79268?hl=en-GB)